# Image Background Issue in IOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am adding imageview in viewcontroller.
It is working good in ios6 but in ios7 It display with white background.

I have tried `clearColor` but it's not working.
Here is my code

```
[imgcharacter setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"character%d.png",reelBtnTag]]];

[imgcharacter setFrame:CGRectMake(100,100, 247.5f, 385.0f)];
imgcharacter.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
 [imgcharacter setBackground : [UIColor clearColor]];          
[captureview addSubview:imgcharacter];
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Have you tried setting the contentView backgroundColor to clearColor? iOS 7 introduces a content view property on a few things that didn't have it before.

Comment: Pragmatically i am dding imageview in viewcontroller.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Have you tried to tried to check if the instance of [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"character%d.png",reelBtnTag]] is good or not?
Can you tell us the type of imgcharacter and captureview?

Comment: ScreenCaptureView *captureview and UIImageView *imgcharacter

Comment: can you post the full party where you making the UIImageView?

Comment: in .h file i take UiImageView *imgcharacter as global and use it into .m file as above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way....

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(Your Image);
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 52, 40, 50)];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    imageView.image = image;
```